# approximation of zeta by dirichlet polynomials

Tags: riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

I was reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04061) in which (at 2.42) it says

$$\sum_{n\leq T}[\frac{1}{n^{1/2+it}} (1-\frac{n}{T})^A] = \zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it) + \mathcal{O}_A(T^{-A/2})$$

I looked online (wikipedia on zeta and on general dirichlet polynomials + google + here) for a proof of this approximation but couldn't find any.

I couldn't prove this myself either: I'm not sure where to start since $\zeta$ cannot be written under this form for $Re(s) < 1$.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: @reuns page 15, equation (2.42)

Comment: It is p.14 and they take $t \in [T,2T]$ so yes this is Riemann-Siegel formula. It doesn't hold for a fixed $t$ and $T \to \infty$, nor for a fixed $T$ and $t \to\infty$ (since it would imply $\zeta(1/2+it)  =O(1)$)

Comment: thanks for the clarification